# Query not inserting data into table however It returns success status

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to insert data in table with following code.

```
$query2 = "insert into  aerion. prosp_contact(prosp_consult_id,contact_id,prosp_contact_type,summary) VALUES(".$pid.",'".$id1."','".$cnt_typ[$i]."','".$cnt_smry[$i]."') ";
$res2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Query returns success status but data is not getting inserted table. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: there is missing single quote in ".$pid."

Comment: echo your query and run into phpmyadmin

Comment: High risk using MySQL, Use MySqli or PDO. MySQL is deprecated.

Comment: I tried echoing query and executing on phpmyadmin....same query is working and also inserting data in table....but through php it is not working

Comment: Maybe you're inserting the rows in a different database. Check your settings. It doesn't make sense for MySQL to not return an error and not to insert it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion....But when I execute query through php...index column count increases by one and no data is inserted also no blank record is inserted......and one more important thing....When I tried same thing by changing table name in both database and query then data is getting inserted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing single qutoation use as

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO  aerion.
   prosp_contact(prosp_consult_id,contact_id,prosp_contact_type,summary)      
  VALUES('".$pid."','".$id1."','".$cnt_typ[$i]."','".$cnt_smry[$i]."') ";
 $res2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for help....I tried using quotation to $pid....But no result....Most important thing is Same query is executing fine on other page.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for trouble,

```
    I found solution. There was error in my logic. row was getting deleted immediately after it was added.
```

Thanks for your time.